# Can we undeploy a Spring container managed bean which is no more needed

Tags: spring

I a get a get a bean from Spring container say

```
MyClass obj1 = Context.getBean("obj1");
```

After using obj1, I am sure that it will not be needed in rest of my application.

Then is there any way to ask Spring container to destroy the bean. 
Atleast giving hint to Spring container that it is no more needed and spring my decide whether to destroy it or not (Similar to garbage collection)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make "obj1" a prototype-scoped bean. Then Spring will create a new instance of it each time you ask for it (make sure you are ok with this), and then it will not manage the instance any further, so when you are done with it and release all your references it can be garbage collected. 
Prototype scope is like `new`, only giving you Spring-configured beans.

Comment: This seems good approach (if application logic is OK with prototype scope).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will be possible for you to tell Spring container to destroy that bean. If you notice most of these beans created by Spring framework are `Singleton` that are supposed to give you same instance of the bean every time you get it injected into your code. A singleton by nature is supposed to live through the life of the application hence it cannot be destroyed.